# Representing a double for-loop as a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What would be the best way to represent the sum formula (series) of this for-loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j+=i)
        count++
```

What process is best to determine this?

**EDIT:**

Sum in this sense: $\sum \limits_{k=1}^N k^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the inner loop increments `count` when $j=1, j=i+1, j=2i+1, \ldots$

If $k$ is the largest integer with $ki+1 \leq n$, then `count` will be incremented $k+1$ times. Therefore, the inner loop increments `count` by $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{i}\rfloor+1.$

Therefore the full formula for the loop is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{i}\right\rfloor+1$$
or
$$n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{i}\right\rfloor.$$

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a nice closed form for that sum, although I couldn't find one with a quick search through tables of floor function identities. Maybe another answer will continue the calculation.

Comment: This is essentially the summatory function of the divisor function.  There isn't any closed form, but the precise asymptotics have been studied extensively (see [Dirichlet divisor problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem)).

Answer (score 1):

One very computationally efficient way would be with the ceiling function,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \bigg\lceil \frac{n}{i} \bigg\rceil.$$

This representation is on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C6%2C9%2C13%2C16%2C21&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: `j += i`, not `j++`

Comment: Could you deduce the closed form of this summation?

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi I have not done any work on proving the matter, but I am pretty sure that no such form exists. Cheers. On an irrelevant matter, I read your Bio. If we did not live on opposite sides of the world we might be famous friends at least in tea, and certainly in math. :)